# Разделить в Python 3 слово на символы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка, к примеру, `"май"` надо сделать так, чтобы получился список примерно такого вида: `['м', 'а', 'й']`.

`split` тут не сработает (по крайней мере, у меня не вышло), так как нет символа, через который можно разделить слово на буквы.

Comment: А в чём задача? Может быть для её решения и в список преобразовывать не надо)

Comment: как раз, надо... Пишу программу для расшифровки шифра цезаря. Там введенные слова нужно в лист запихнуть, как мне кажется :)

Answer (score 9):

Строка (например,`"май"`) -- это неизменяемая последовательность Юникодных символов (Unicode code points) в Питоне 3. Поэтому достаточно просто передать строку в `list()`, чтобы получить список символов (изменяемая последовательность).

Некоторые буквы могут состоять из нескольких символов, например, `ё` буква может быть представлена как U+0435 U+0308 последовательносить символов в NFD форме ([Unicode normalization forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)):

```
>>> print(u'\u0435\u0308')
ё
```

Если хочется найти именно буквы, а не символы, то можно использовать `\X` регулярное выражение для букв ([eXtended grapheme clusters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)):

```
>>> list(u'\u0435\u0308\u0436')
['е', '̈', 'ж']
>>> import regex # $ pip install regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\X', u'\u0435\u0308\u0436', regex.U)
['ё', 'ж']
```

В данном случае строка содержит три символа, но только две буквы.

В общем случае, не все видимые символы могут быть представлены в виде единственной Unicode codepoint, то есть NFD не является единственной причиной, что некоторые символы на экране могут быть представлены в виде нескольких Unicode codepoints ([см. примеры в ссылке выше](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)).

Answer (score 8):

Как-то так:

```
print(list("abcd"))
```

Если нужно пройти по всем сиволам, то

```
for c in "abcd":
    ...
```

Comment: Но зачем? "abcd"[0] = 'a'.

Answer (score -2):

Если по-простому, без regex, можно просто и явно:

```
char_list = []  # объявляем пустой список
string = 'май'
for c in string: # идем по строке
    char_list.append(c) # добавляем буквы в список
print(char_list)  # >>>> ['м', 'а', 'й']
```

Comment: Просто и явно - это `list(s)`. Ваш вариант более длинный и медленный, т.к. процесс будет идти не во встроенной функции Python (изначально написанной на Си, и скомпилированной, поэтому быстрой), а в интерпретируемом коде.