# Как найти слово, в котором число различных символов минимально?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Как найти слово, в котором число различных символов минимально? Если таких слов несколько, найти первое из них.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я думаю в качестве ответа подойдут слова а, и, б, о, у, я, ее, с, к, в, ну и т.п.

Comment: уточните что вы понимаете под символом? (байт, Unicode codepoint, символы, видимые на экране?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что вам нужно в заданной строке найти слово, в котором число УНИКАЛЬНЫХ символов минимально (сколько раз они повторяются неважно)? Тогда что-то типа такого (если разделитель слов — пробелы):

```
def f(string):
    for i in string.split(' '):
        if (len(set(string)) > len(set(i))):
            string = i
    return string
```

**UPD**

Добавил вариант на случай ввода строки в форме NFD (спасибо @jfs):

```
import regex
def f1(string):

    def uniq(s):
        return regex.findall(r'\X', s, regex.U)

    for i in string.split(' '):
        if (len(uniq(string)) > len(uniq(i))):
            string = i
    return string
```

Comment: поправьте отступ -- это имеет значение в Питоне. Следует уточнить что символом является (знать о Unicode normalization forms и eXtended grapheme clusters) иначе сюрпризы будут, [например](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458509/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо за комментарий, при переносе из редактора таки не поставил нужное количество пробелов. А насчет символов: не вижу смысла передавать строку в форме `u'\u0435\u0308'` в третьем питоне (мало того, что до 3.3 не поддерживалось, так еще и пример по вашей ссылке например не всегда получается воспроизвести (на Win7 Python 3.4.3 не работает, на той же версии питона в убунте работает)). PS а почему в ответе по ссылке не используете встроенный модуль `re`?

Comment: Вы понимаете что способ ввода тут не причём? Вы не контролируете что вам на вход может прийти. Если не знаете что такое NFD или что `re` не поддерживает `\X`, то хотя бы попробовали бы код прежде чем комментировать.

Comment: `regex.findall()` возвращает список, вы хотите `len(set()` вызвать дополнительно. Человеко-читаемые буквы могут состоять из нескольких Unicode codepoints и в NFC. Для ясности, я бы изолировал функцию, которая разбивает текст на слова, от функции, которая работает пытается минимум найти -- у вас неверная реализация.

Comment: @jfs да, не заметил, что забыл `len`, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 0):

Если символ это Unicode codepoint, то чтобы найти слово с минимальным кол-вом символов из списка `words`:

```
word = min(words, key=lambda w: len(set(w)))
```

Если символ это символ, видимый пользователю (grapheme cluster):

```
import regex as re # pip install regex
word = min(words, key=lambda w: len(set(re.findall(r'\X', w))))
```

Если слова в тексте разделены символами пробелов (включая новый строки и Юникодные символы), то `words = text.split()`.