# Найти слово, состоящее только из различных символов

Tags: python

Как найти слово, состоящее только из различных символов? Если таких слов несколько, найти первое из них.

Например: Например, строка имеет слова с разными символами (am, studying, new, and, want, to, learn, lot)

```
string = "I am studying programming. I'm new and I want to learn a lot."
```

Но есть несколько, мне нужно найти первый (am).

Пожалуйста, как можно найти?

Comment: Почему `am`, если `I` первое слово и удовлетворяет условию? Разбейте строку на слова, в цикле проверяйте содержит ли слово повторяющиеся символы, если нет, то мы закончили, если да, то переходим к следующему слову. Вы сами решить попробуйте, больше толка будет.

Comment: самый простой способ проверить слово на наличие повторяющихся букв - оставить буквы только в одном экземпляре и сравнить число исходных и полученных символов, например, через `len(set(word)) == len(word)`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: что значит ["символ"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458509/23044) в вашем случае?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ зависит от того, что вы понимаете под символом, например, если символ это Unicode codepoint, то:

```
word = next(w for w in words if len(w) == len(set(w)))
```

Если хочется буквы, видимые пользователю, считать:

```
import regex as re # pip install regex

chars = lambda word: re.findall(r'\X', word)
word = next(w for w in words if len(chars(w)) == len(set(chars(w))))
```

Процедура разбиения текста на слова зависит от задачи, например:

```
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', string)
>>> words
['I', 'am', 'studying', 'programming', 'I', 'm', 'new', 'and', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'learn', 'a', 'lot']
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот сделел как советовал ВОРОН

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Как найти слово, состоящее только из различных символов? Если таких слов несколько, найти первое из них.

all_word = "I am studying programming. I'm new and I want to learn a lot." # Задаем строку в которой будем искать слова
matrix=all_word.split() # преобразуем строку в список
for one_word in matrix: # Перебираем все слова в списке
    if len(one_word)>1: # отбрасываем слова короче 2х символов
        if len(set(one_word)) == len(one_word): # проверяем повторяются ли символы в слове
            print(one_word)
```

Comment: это ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Да, попробовал работает