# В чем ошибка??? Программа должна печатать список в обратном порядке

Tags: python

Программа должна печатать список в обратном порядке через пробел.

Ввод: Питон
Вывод: Нотип

```
N = raw_input()
l = []


l.append(N)

print(" ".join(l.reverse()))
```

Comment: Приведите пример тестовых входных данных и желаемый результат.

Comment: Вы reverse вызываете для списка в котором всего один элемент. вызовите `print(N.reverse())`

Comment: @Avernial: `.reverse()` как и другие методы, которые изменяют объект, всегда возвращает `None` в Питоне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `reverse` объекта `list` не возвращает список.

Чтобы работало правильно:

```
N = raw_input()
l = []
l.append(N)

# 1 вариант
l.reverse()
print(" ".join(l))

# 2 вариант (в этом случаи будет создана и возвращена из 
# reversed копия списка в обратном порядке)
print(" ".join(reversed(l)))
```

---

Согласно уточнению добавлю вариации:

```
# Реверс содержимого списка
print(" ".join([reversed(item) for item in l]))

# Реверс содержимого списка с реверсированием списка
print(" ".join(reversed([reversed(item) for item in l])))

# Реверс строки, что добавляется в список
print(reversed(N))
```

Comment: К сожалению оба ваши варианта выдают слово python, не переворачивая его.

Comment: Так вам нужно список реверсировать или содержимое списка, или содержимое списка и сам список?

Comment: к вашему варианту c двумя `reversed()`, есть алгоритм, которые позволяет слова во фразе переставить, не используя дополнительной памяти: [Efficiently reverse the order of the words (not characters) in an array of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете список и строку. Чтобы инвертировать строку:

```
n = input()
print(n[::-1])
```

Comment: нужно быть осторожным с буквами, которые более одного символа в строке могут занимать (иногда),  [к примеру, `'ё'` (лучше список получить, а его уже переставлять)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458509/23044)