# Длина строки считается неверно: unicode в python 2.7

Tags: python, строки, python-2.x, unicode

Вычисляю длину строки. Но длина строки (наверное) считается удвоенной для русских символов. Для цифр -- нет. Например:

```
len("ул Весёлая") == 1 + 2 * 9 // (Пробел + русские символы (*2))
len("ул Весёлая 71") == 1 + 2 * 9 + 1 + 3 // (Пробел + русские символы (*2) + пробел + 2 цифры)
```

Есть ли функция в питоне, которая считает истиную длину строки, а не количество байтов (считается, наверное, именно кол-во байтов).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема не возникает, если использовать правильные(unicode) строки:

```
>>> print(len('ул Весенняя 13'))
24
>>> print(len(u'ул Весенняя 13'))
14
```

Можно самостоятельно декодировать простые строки:

```
>>> print(len('ул Весенняя 13'.decode("utf-8")))
14
```

---

В python3 нет такой проблемы, потому что строки по умолчанию в utf-8:

```
>>> print(len('ул Весенняя 13'))
14
>>> print(len(u'ул Весенняя 13'))
14
```

---

В общем случае(полный набор символов unicode) задача найти длину строки не является тривиальной.

Во первых, нужно определиться с самим термином - что понимать под длиной строки?

Варианты:

- количество байт в utf-8 представлении (24 выше)
- количество unicode символов (14 выше)
  *можно посчитать, как количество всех байт, кроме диапазона (0x80-0xBF).*
- количество видимых знаков
- количество занятых знакомест
  *Нужно исключить диакритику и прочие символы, не занимающие места*

Положение усугубляется ещё и тем, что одни и те же строки могут быть закодированы разными последовательностями unicode codepoints. Для определённости можно "нормализовать" строку, например, с помощью `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', ustr)`

```
>>> len(regex.findall(ur'[\0-\u02FF\u0370-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u20CF\u2100-\uD7FF\uDC00-\uFE1F\uFE30-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\u0300-\u036F\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u20D0-\u20FF\uFE20-\uFE2F]', unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍̑͗̎̅͛́Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘!̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͞')))
6
```

Comment: Ага, разобрался. Спасибо. Чем отличается 'ул Весенняя 13'.decode("utf-8"), u'ул Весенняя 13', unicode(s1, "utf-8")? Есть ли отличия между " " и ' '?

Comment: Тем, что decode можно применить к переменной

Comment: Какие кавычки использовать - тема для отдельного холивара =)

Comment: [как я вам уже говорил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/%D0%9E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85#comment17881_4907): выучите разницу между понятиями кодировка, байты, Unicode. `utf-8` это кодировка (одна из многих). Понятие кодировки к Юникодной строке не применимо (внутреннее представление -- это деталь реализации). Одну и ту же Unicode строчку можно в байты превратить, используя самые разные кодировки.

Comment: мне всё равно кто автор. Важно, что информация в ответе вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Что именно вводит в этом ответе неверно? Строки в кодировке utf-8 - это unicode строки. Потому что utf-8 - unicode кодировка. строковые литералы в третьем питоне кодируются в utf-8. **Где именно тут введение в заблужение??** `Понятие кодировки к Юникодной строке не применимо` - к абстрактной - да, но в данном куске памяти строка всегда в некоторой кодировке.

Comment: Напишите свой "верный" ответ, наконец - с *правильным* употреблением терминов. Это ведь так **важно**.

Comment: если вы не понимаете разницу между utf-8 и Unicode в Питоне, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Константы (string literals) `""` создают байтовые строки в Питоне 2 (если `from __future__ import unicode_literals` не включено). Поэтому `len("abc")` возвращает количество байт.

`u""` является строковой константой, которая всегда Unicode строки создаёт.
`len(u"abc")` вернёт количество Юникодных символов (Unicode codepoint).

Некоторые буквы (user-perceived characters) могут состоять из нескольких символов. В этом случае, можно `\X` регулярное выражение использовать, чтобы найти количество "неразрывных/слитных" элементов текста (eXtended grapheme clusters):

```
>>> import regex # $ pip install regex
>>> text = u'я  ё'         
>>> print(repr(text))
u'\u044f \U0001f602 \u0435\u0308'  # 6 code points
>>> regex.findall(ur'\X', text)    # 5 grapheme clusters
[u'\u044f', u' ', u'\U0001f602', u' ', u'\u0435\u0308'] 
>>> print " | ".join(regex.findall(ur'\X', text)) 
я |   |  |   | ё  # 5 user-perceived characters
```

Дополнительно, существуют так называемые узкие сборки Питона 2, в которых не BMP-символы такие как  представляются в виде utf-16 суррогатной пары (surrogate pair) — нарушение абстракции, что Юникодная строка является неизменяемой последовательностью Unicode сodepoint.

Вот ещё пример [одного знака](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618487/4279) ([emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)), который из нескольких юникод-cимволов состоит:

```
>>> emoji = u'\U0001f469\u200d\U0001f469\u200d\U0001f467\u200d\U0001f466'
>>> print(emoji)
‍‍‍
>>> len(emoji)
7
>>> len(regex.findall(u'\X', emoji))
1
```

С точки зрения движения курсора, выделения, копирования, итд — этот [эмодзи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8) это один GUI элемент.

- [Как разбить строку на отдельные символы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597090/23044)
- [Разделить в Python 3 слово на символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458373/23044)

Для текстовых интерфейсов может иметь значение ширина напечатанной строки в терминале. [`python-prompt-toolkit`](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) использует [`wcwidth` модуль](https://github.com/jquast/wcwidth):

```
>>> import wcwidth  # $ pip install wcwidth
>>> wcwidth.wcswidth(emoji)
8
```