# Отсортировать список предложений по количеству букв и слов в python 2.7

Tags: python, сортировка, python-2.7

Начинаю учить Python 2.7. Надо отсортировать список предложений по количеству букв и слов. song - собственно сам файл со списком.

Чтобы отсортировать, подозреваю, надо играться с key, но не хватает у меня пока мыслей, как именно.

```
song = sys.argv[1]
w = open(song)
for line in sorted(w, key = int(len(line)))   
    print line
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Длина строки считается неверно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649587/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр `key` должен быть функцией, принимающей текущий элемент и возвращающей значение, по которому сортируем. В данном случае достаточно просто `len` (приведение длины к целому излишне, т.к. `len` и так возвращает целое число):

```
song = sys.argv[1]
w = open(song)
for line in sorted(w, key=len)   
    print line
```

В более сложных случаях сортировки может понадобиться создать lambda-функцию (или даже выносить код в отдельную именованную функцию).

Для сортировки по количеству слов можно разбивать строку по пробельным символам с помощью метода строки `split`, и сортировать по количеству полученных кусков:

```
song = sys.argv[1]
w = open(song)
for line in sorted(w, key=lambda x: len(x.split()))
    print line
```

Чтобы отсортировать строки по количеству слов, а слова в строках по количеству букв, можно сделать так:

Сначала просто создаем список строк, каждую строку разбиваем на слова:

```
lines = [line.rstrip().split() for line in file]
```

Добавляем сортировку слов внутри строк (это та же строка, просто добавили сортировку):

```
lines = [sorted(line.rstrip().split(), key=len) for line in file]
```

Добавляем сортировку строк по количеству слов (заменяю генератор списка на итератор - круглые скобки вместо квадратных):

```
lines = sorted((sorted(line.rstrip().split(), key=len) for line in file), key=len)
```

Т.к. строки уже разбиты на слова, то еще раз делать `split` не нужно, а просто сортируем по длине списка.

Ну и при выводе на экран собираем списки слов обратно в целые строки:

```
for line in lines:
    print ' '.join(line)
```

**Дополнение.** Как правильно заметил jfs в комментариях к ответу, если файл сохранен например в utf-8 (вообще в любой не однобайтовой кодировке), то будет не подсчет символов, а подсчет байт, плюс не будет работать разбивка по юникодным пробельным символам.

Чтобы открыть файл в нужной кодировке, нужно использовать функцию [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open). При открытии будет использоваться кодировка системы по-умолчанию. Чтобы использовать конкретную кодировку, можно указать ее при открытии:

```
import io
...
w = io.open(song, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: а для того, чтобы сортировать слова внутри каждого предложения по количеству букв, надо их разбить на x.strip().split(), правильно понимаю? используя при этом lambda

Comment: @ЕкатеринаНагорная, добавил пример сортировки строк по количеству слов и слов внутри строк по количеству букв.

Comment: да уж, до такого мой пока еще маленький программистский мозг бы не додумался) Спасибо за подробное объяснение

Comment: @ЕкатеринаНагорная, ну мне тут тоже пришлось немного задуматься, как получше реализовать)

Comment: 1- вы текст как байты читаете, поэтому `len` возвращает количество байтов в слове, что в общем случае может отличаться от количества букв 2- `.split()` на байтах игнорирует Юникодные пробелы (к примеру неразрывный пробел). В целом разбиение по пробелам может мусор оставить. Сравните: `u"Миру — мир!".encode('utf-8').split()`, `u"Миру — мир!".split()` и `re.findall(r'\w+', u"Миру — мир!", flags=re.U)`. По мелочи:  3- `print line` дублирует строки у вас. print печатает строку, плюс сама line может окончание строки содержать 4- используйте with-конструкцию для файлов, особенно в коде для новичков

Comment: комментарий съел неразрывный пробел, строка должна была быть: `u'Миру —\xa0мир!'`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отсортировать список предложений `sentences` по количеству слов:

```
sentences.sort(key=word_count)
```

где функция `word_count()` принимает предложение и возвращает количество слов в нём.

Если вы ещё хотите, чтобы слова внутри отдельных предложений были отсортированы по количеству букв, то следует разбить каждое предложение на слова и отсортировать слова:

```
words = get_words(sentence)
words.sort(key=char_count)
```

Здесь `get_words()` функция принимает предложение и возвращает список слов в нём. `char_count()` функция принимает слово и возвращает количество букв в нём.

Как конкретно выглядят функции word_count, get_word, char_count зависит существенно от задачи.

К примеру, если входной файл, заданный в командной строке, содержит предложения каждое на новой строке, а слова просто отделены пробелом, тогда чтобы отсортировать предложения по количеству слов в них, а слова внутри предложений по количеству букв:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import sys

with io.open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    sentences = file.read().splitlines()  # NOTE: line ends are not included
    result = sorted([sorted(get_words(s), key=char_count)
                     for s in sentences], key=word_count)

for words in result: # for each sentence
    print(' '.join(words))
```

где:

```
get_words = unicode.split  # split on arbitrary whitespace
word_count = len           # number of items in the list of words
char_count = len           # unicode word length
```

Замечания по коду:

- [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) используется, чтобы текст как unicode прочитать, а не байты (используя [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) кодировку). Количество байт в слове может не совпадать с количеством символов в нём. См. [Длина строки считается неверно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649587/23044)
- [`unicode.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines) возвращает список строк, убирая концы строк
- `unicode.split()` разбивает строку по произвольному пробелу (не только `u' '`, но к примеру и неразрывный пробел [U+00A0](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0) понимает). В качестве альтернативы, можно было бы регулярное выражение использовать, чтобы список слов получить:

  ```
  import re

  words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
  ```

  это полезно, если вы не хотите к примеру, пунктуацию рассматривать частью слов (если просто по пробелам разбить, то точки, запятые в словах остаются)
- `word_count = len` работает, так как каждое предложение как список слов представлено в коде
- `unicode` объект в Питоне является неизменяемой последовательностью символов (Unicode codepoints), поэтому `char_count = len`. То есть количество букв считается равным количеству символов в слове. Стоит заметить, что одно видимая буква, может из нескольких символов состоять:

  ```
  >>> len(u"ё")
  2
  >>> u"ё"
  u'\u0435\u0308'
  ```

  Для целей перемещения по тексту, для копирования в GUI мы бы не хотели только половину буквы получить. См. [Разделить в Python 3 слово на символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458373/23044)

  Дополнительно, существуют так называемые "узкие" сборки python 2 исполняемого файла, в которых не-BMP символы такие как [U+1F602 (FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY)](https://codepoints.net/U+1f602) в виде суррогатной пары представлены (абстракция нарушена — дефект в реализации). В "широких" сборках (часто на Linux) или на Питоне 3 этой проблемы не существует: индексация (Unicode) строк не разбивает символ (Unicode codepoint):

  ```
  >>> print(u'\U0001f602')

  >>> len(_)
  1
  ```