# Как в Python выбрать первую и последнюю букву в слове?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Задача: Написать игру виселица на Python.
Проблема: Необходимо выбрать первую и последнюю буквы  в слове.
Вопрос: Как в Python выбрать первую и последнюю букву  в слове?

Answer (score 7):

```
first, last = word[0], word[-1]
```

Comment: Можно упомянуть, что в общем случае, для разбивки слова на буквы, полезно знать о Unicode нормализации, grapheme clusters. [Разделить в Python 3 слово на символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458373/23044)

Answer (score 2):

arguments packing/unpacking

```
# 'д'    []       'а'
(first, *middle, last) = 'да'

# 'с' ['л', 'о', 'в'] 'о'
(first, *middle, last) = 'слово'

# first="с", f="л", m="['о']", l="в", last="о"
(first, *(f, *m, l), last) = 'слово'
print('first="{first}", f="{f}", m="{m}", l="{l}", last="{last}"'.format(**vars()))
```